# mobile browser simulator

Tags: html, browser, simulator

I have started coding for mobile browsers (i.e. iPad, Galaxy Tab, etc). For a starter, I don't have budgets to get all the tablets for testing (I wish I do :D). Anyway, I am looking for a decent mobile browser simulators. I have looked into Ripple (only works in Chrome), MobiOne, and PhoneGap simulator. But all of these are not that up to par. Can someone recommended a decent one? and it will be great if it is also open source.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good list of emulators and simulators are here: http://www.mobilexweb.com/emulators

Comment: Cool. I am going to check this out.

Answer (score 0):

For iPad, the only simulator I know of is built into XCode when you compile or run. You have an option of previewing in iPhone or iPad, and though the screen is hard to read, it's manageable if you click on 2x button.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the downside with this is that you have to work in OSX. Unfortunately I have to switch between Windows and OSX all the time. It will be great if there is one unified simulator that works on both platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing for android, the Android SDK has one.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to quickly view how a webpage would render at various mobile device resolutions then here is a nice little webpage...

http://synthphone.com

you can even link directly to a url via query strings. for example, here is one that should load the Sencha Touch 2 carousel. Use your mouse like a finger to slide around the images etc.

http://www.synthphone.com/?u=http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/carousel/index.html

have fun!